# Flexbox, white-space and ellipsis

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a row where I try to manage flexbox, when I reduce the width of this row, I want to see **ellipsis** for the **subject** and the **recipients**.

Currently, my code doesn't work well because the right part is pushed when I resize the window.

```css
.row {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.checkbox {
  order: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.metadata {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.subject, .recipients {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.date, .labels {
  order: 1;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.badge {
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row flex">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </label>
        <div class="metadata">
            <div class="flex">
                <a href="#" class="subject">Long long long long long long long subject</a>
                <div class="date">
                    <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> 12 fevrier 2016 <a href=""><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="recipients"><strong>Recipient1, Recipient2, Recipient3</strong></div>
                <div class="labels">
                    <span class="badge">Badge 1</span>
                    <span class="badge">Badge 2</span>
                    <span class="badge">Badge 3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Here a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hegilal/1/edit?html,css,output) with my current problem.

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Just apply `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your inner flex container.

**CSS**

```
.metadata .flex {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Here is a working example:

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/3d4yqaub/2/)

***Side Note:** You don't need to specify `order: 0;` because in flex-box, order is set to 0 by default.

Comment: I don't like use `float: left;` why I cannot use flex inside flex? Secondly, I prefer keep the `checkbox` label outside the `.metadata` element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice clean, modern solution, depending on [what you need to support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clamp).

```
display: -webkit-box;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-line-clamp: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Stick that on your **.subject, .recipients** class.

Comment: You can solve this with flexbox so you can have better browser support. Checkout my answer to see how.

Comment: Modern? This syntax is obsolete